# What's the difference between the "-teer" and "-ter" suffix?

Tags: suffixes

- RackeTEER, but not rackeTER
- PuppeTEER, but not puppeTER
- PrivaTEER, but not privaTER

Related: in my industry, we see *both* "marketer" and "marketeer."

Why? Is it just stylistic? Is there a semantic difference?

Comment: Have you looked at the difference in the dictionary definitions of "marketer" and "marketeer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oxford Languages says that the suffix *-eer* forming a noun means 'a person concerned with or engaged in an activity'. (*Privateer* was coined because the people concerned were private individuals and not naval personnel.)

*-er* is just the ordinary suffix to a verb meaning 'a person who does that activity'. So you can say *marketer* because *market* can be a verb as well as a noun, but *puppet* and *private* aren't verbs, and *racket* can be but not in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

Every English word has a different history; if it's borrowed, which is likely, then it was borrowed at a particular  time, from a particular speech group or dialect, by particular people, in a particular place, for their own particular reasons. And all of those particulars were **different** for each word in the language. And we don't know them and never will, though we can guess in some cases.

In the case of the *-te(e)r* agentive, I would guess (without looking it up in the dictionary, which could already have been done) that *-teer* words are French borrowings from words in *-tier*, while the others aren't. They're all from the same PIE root, but via different routes is my guess. But that's just a guess. There are about a million words in English, and nobody knows more than a tenth of them, let alone all their etymologies. Language is not so well organized as that.

Comment: It's not just the derivations. The suffixes are usually used differently, as described in Kate's answer.